# Delagate static IPv6 Prefix

Tags: ipv6

Is there a way to configure a router to obtain allways the same prefix form an upstream router in my network? In my case I have a FritzBox connected to internet and behind it a OpenWrt router.

Comment: To which router address are you referring? Every router interface has an address, and you normally configure router interfaces with static addresses.

Comment: I think the question is "how to make DHCPv6-PD always give out the same prefix", is that correct?

Comment: OpenWrt can be given an IPv6 assignment hint, but the upstream DHCPv6 server has to honor it. I have no idea if the FritzBox does so.